# Eclipse Mars plugin dependencies issues

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to intall [Jaspersoft Studio](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jaspersoft-studio#group-details) from Eclipse Market place (Mars Version).

> The problem is that, the operation cannot performed due to dependencies.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Jaspersoft Studio feature 6.3.1.final (com.jaspersoft.studio.feature.feature.group 6.3.1.final)
  Missing requirement: JasperReports Feature 6.3.1.final (net.sf.jasperreports.feature.feature.group 6.3.1.final) requires 'org.apache.commons.dbcp 1.4.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Jaspersoft Studio feature 6.3.1.final (com.jaspersoft.studio.feature.feature.group 6.3.1.final)
    To: net.sf.jasperreports.feature.feature.group [6.3.1.final]
```

I try to resolve the problem by installing [org.apache.commons.dbcp](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi?Preferred=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-eu.apache.org%2Fdist%2F), I downloaded the zip package, and trying to install by doing following steps. (Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Archieve).

> But i got Error: No Software site found at jar:file:/E:/commons-dbcp2-2.1.1-bin.zip!/. Do you wish to edit the location.

I already search and looked at some solution but non of them help me.

> Am i doing something wrong? I am looking for solution or alternative ways.
>
> > Any help would be highly appreciated.
> >     Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Update site for JasperSoft Studio Plugin. It works for me. It will work for you.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperstudio/files/updatesite/6.3.1/

Comment: Worked for me too. JasperStudio was installed without problem on Neon.1 (4.6.1) but got this issue using Neon.2 (4.6.2)

Answer (score 4):

When I have issue with the marketplace installer, I usually install the software through the UpdateSite URL listed in the Marketplace Page.

So, I checked the [Eclipse Marketplace page for Jasper Studio](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jaspersoft-studio), and I copied the update site URL, as you can see below.

[image: Get the update site URL]

But, when I tried to access the update site webpage, I realized the page is not available. (perhaps is just a problem of SourceForge)

[image: Tentative to access the Update Site URL]

I wonder if, in your case, the problem is caused by missing update site content.

I suggest you try installing JasperSoft Studio via Update Site URL. If this does not work, I suggest contacting the developers and ask them whether the update site URL is mantained or not.

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i understand what your are trying to say about update site URL but the problem is related to the org.apache.commons.dbcp 1.4.0 as well, Some type of dependencies issues.